# Как добавить кнопку в TitleBar?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Как можно добавить кнопку в TitleBar окна?

[image: Пример из Win10 приложения]

Comment: укажите точнее местоположение элемента. Выражение "в верхнюю панель окна" не совсем однозначное

Comment: @YuriiManziuk, обновил скрин. Я так понимаю эта панель называется TitleBar?

Comment: да, это `TitleBar`

Comment: Именно кнопку "Назад" или какую-нибудь другую?

Comment: Да мне вообще любую кнопку. Просто хочу понять как на 'TitleBar' добавить свой контрол.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, вам нужен [`RibbonWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonwindow.aspx) — это тип окна, как у MS Office. Позволяет делать окна такого вида:

[image: Ribbon window]

Вот документация:

- [Ribbon (WPF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Ribbon Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386097.aspx)
- [WPF Team Blog: Introducing Microsoft Ribbon for WPF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2010/08/03/introducing-microsoft-ribbon-for-wpf/)

---

Ну или вы можете использовать класс `WindowChrome` из `Ribbon`'а или nuget-пакета `Microsoft.Windows.Shell` (добавьте его через `Install-Package Microsoft.Windows.Shell` в консоли менеджера пакетов).

Вот такой код:

```
<Window x:Class="CustomNonClientArea.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomNonClientArea"
        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Windows.Shell"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="local:MainWindow">
            <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <shell:WindowChrome/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border Margin="{Binding WindowNonClientFrameThickness,
                                       Source={x:Static shell:SystemParameters2.Current}}">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </Border>
                            <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Margin="2"
                                    shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                                Йо-хо-хо!
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    <Grid Background="Green"/>
</Window>
```

убирает иконку и `Caption`, и взамен даёт вам рисовать что вам вздумается.

[image: результат]

Подробная документация здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.shell.windowchrome.aspx

---

**Обновление**: В Visual Studio 2015 грузить `Microsoft.Windows.Shell` с nuget уже не нужно, всё доступно и так.

Изменения в XAML:

```
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Shell;assembly=PresentationFramework"
```

и

```
Margin="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness}}"
```

---

Альтернативный вариант — писать собственные велосипед через P/Invoke: убрать стандартный title bar (`WindowStyle = None`), рисовать non-client area вручную, и обрабатывать `NC_`-оконные сообщения. Это не так уж сложно, но работы довольно много.

Comment: `Microsoft.Windows.Shell ` мне идеально подошел, спасибо!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!